How do I link my values to a specific column of a shapefile for coloring the map in python?
I am trying to color a map based on on values from a csv file. One shapefile works very well, linking the csv to the shapefile based on the header "ADM1_EN" as per per shap shapefile example row 1 and 2 below
         ADM1_EN ADM1_PCODE ADM1_TYPE                                           geometry
0          Berea        LSD  District  POLYGON ((27.98656 -28.94791, 27.98670 -28.948...

The other shapefile, on the other hand is difficult fo me to handle
               shapeName shapeISO                  shapeID shapeGroup shapeType                                           geometry
0     Mokhotlong District     LS-J  63558799B62052207870559        LSO      ADM1  POLYGON ((28.79248 -28.90741, 28.79586 -28.908...

I have tried linking on shapeName, it doesn't work. I tried to link on column=2, no success
help will be appreciated.
